# How can you call different aggregate operations on pandas groubpy object

Tags: pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby, mean

```
df.groupby("home_team_name")["home_team_goal_count","away_team_goal_count"].sum()
```

I want to group examples in my data-frame based on the variable `home_team_name` I would like to perform different operations on different attributes. I want sum one of them and mean for one of them and the last occurence for another.

As of now I only know how to perform the same operation on all of them like in my code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
df.groupby("home_team_name").agg({'home_team_goal_count': sum,
                                  'away_team_goal_count': np.mean})
```

Refer to more examples in [`documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

To get the [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) value, you could do:

```
df.groupby("home_team_name").agg({'home_team_goal_count': 'last',
                                      'away_team_goal_count': 'last'})
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you what should to get the last example of an column in the group. By last I am refering to its position in the original dataframe.

Comment: Correct, Thank you.